# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDevelopmentDebugBuild' Error in Android

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

When I update my crashlytics library from:

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

TO:

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.2.2'
```

I am getting error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDevelopmentDebugBuild'.
     > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration 
    ':app:DevelopmentDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
     > Could not find com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.0.0.
```

Please help me to solve this error Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) on how to add crashlytics to an Android Project, since that doesn't seem to be the correct artifact. (Maybe you missed the fact that Crashlytics [was acquired](https://techcrunch.com/2017/01/18/google-twitter-fabric/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9kdWNrZHVja2dvLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAAHs-ty7PVUT-i5bu7IjmUZV37rPoeY_F5AOJEC0ndZ4egfg-LXmIKhI3yrQcxrwBLKAul3eLASDJQ2q9wrSijrwviC7KvVVbaacoSh1R0BMihFaKNiUcD4GR5WEFZFnSqFsvg_lEIy8mxv4EUMe7YJtONoIF7s4OFuZnhLDwBgf) by Google).

Answer (score 0):

As per [official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), the recent `implementation` should be:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.6'
```

In addition to that, Crashlytics is now one of Firebase services. You need to configure the project with Firebase as a prerequisite, as @MartinMarconcini suggested.